# I want to get dpkt module for Python and i have not idea. I need to intercept traffic from vpn

Tags: python, macos, pip

*haskelltime:Desktop kasimov$ pip search dpkt*
dpkt                      - dumb packet module

dpkt-fix                  - dumb packet module

INSTALLED: 1.7 (latest)

*haskelltime:Desktop kasimov$ pip install dpkt*

Downloading/unpacking dpkt

Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement dpkt

Cleaning up...

No distributions at all found for dpkt

Storing complete log in /Users/kasimov/.pip/pip.log

Comment: What is your problem ? Please give us more informations.

Comment: pip finds to dpkt module, but i can't download him

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do a `pip search dpkt` you will see there is also a *dpkt-fix* module available.  This module installs fine for me and seems to work:

```
pip install dpkt-fix
```